Well-embedded type property for bounded functions
According to @Tyrone the term well-embedded set was first used in Measures on Metacompact Spaces by W. Moran.
In the article Extensions of Zero-sets and of Real-valued Functions by R. Blair and A. Hager the property well-embedded is named property $\gamma$, and its shown there that property $\beta$ is the analogue of property $\gamma$ for bounded functions:

$S\subseteq X$ has property $\beta$ if for any two zero-sets $Z_1, Z_2$ of $X$ such that $Z_1\cap Z_2\cap S =\emptyset$, the sets $Z_1\cap S$ and $Z_2\cap S$ are completely separated (in $X$).

Namely, $S$ has property $\gamma$ (property $\beta$) if every (bounded) continuous function which extends to a cozero set, extends to the whole space.
Does property $\beta$ has a specific name in the literature, just like set with property $\gamma$ is called well-embedded?

No one seems to know of any name for it. I propose the term well$^*$-embedded. Then $C$-embedded sets are $z$-embedded well-embedded sets, and $C^*$-embedded sets are $z$-embedded well$^*$-embedded sets.

You seem to be referencing a claim, presumably here on MO, by user @Tyrone. Where was this claim made?

@LSpice here
